# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de trabajar con datos de un archivo CSV de gran tamaño?

Tags: c#, csv, estructuras-de-datos, optimización, busqueda

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto propio para practicar un poco en c# y a lo largo de dicho proyecto me he encontrado con varias dudas/problemas sobre el cómo trabajar de manera optima con datos provenientes de un archivo CSV de gran tamaño. A continuación las dudas:

1. En el proyecto en el que estoy trabajando, lo único que hace el programa con los datos del archivo CSV son operaciones de búsqueda (Buscar por fecha, buscar por un identificador etc.), entonces mi pregunta es, ¿Debo tener todos los datos del CSV, **que son aproximadamente 450.000**, almacenados en memoria con alguna estructura de datos para poder realizar dichas búsquedas?
2. Con respecto al punto anterior y, si es necesario tener los datos en memoria, ¿Cuál seria la mejor manera de almacenarlos o qué estructura me recomiendan para que no lleve mucho tiempo realizar las búsquedas? Por mi parte yo he pensado en realizar una especie de lista de adyacencia con una HashTable, en donde la clave seria el identificador del dato **(que no es unico, sino que varios datos pueden tener el mismo identificador)** y el valor una List con todos los datos que tienen en común dicho identificador ¿Es esta una buena implementación y serviría para este proyecto?
3. ¿Qué podría mejorar de este método que es el que lee los datos? ya que al ejecutarse tarda mucho tiempo en leer toda esa cantidad de datos o, ¿Qué paquete Nuget me recomiendan que podría ayudarme?
   He aquí el codigo:

```
public void ReadData()
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FLIGHT_DATA_PATH);
            String line = sr.ReadLine();
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            
            while (line != null)
            {
                String[] data = line.Split(';');

                String date = data[0];
                String tailNumber = data[1];
                String flightNumber = data[2];
                String originCity = CitiesUbications(data[3], data[4]);
                String destinationCity = CitiesUbications(data[5], data[6]);
                String hour = data[7];
                String arivalTime = data[8];
                String airTime = data[10];
                String distance = data[11];

                CreateFlights(date, tailNumber, flightNumber, originCity, destinationCity, hour, arivalTime, airTime, distance);

                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
```

Código del método CitiesUbications que se llama dentro de la funcion ReadData

```
private String CitiesUbications(String city, String state)
        {
            String ubication = "";

            String[] data = city.Split(',');
            ubication = data[0] + ", " + state;

            return ubication;
        }
```

Código del método CreateFlights que se llama dentro de la funcion ReadData

```
private void CreateFlights(String date, String tailNumber, String flightNumber, String originCity, String destinationCity, String hour, String arivalTime, String airTime, String distance)
        {
            Flight flight = new Flight(date, tailNumber, flightNumber, originCity, destinationCity, hour, arivalTime, airTime, distance);

            if (flights.ContainsKey(originCity))
            {
                flights[originCity].Add(flight);
            }
            else
            {
                flights.Add(originCity, new List<Flight>());
                flights[originCity].Add(flight);
            }
        }
```

Por si algo:

1. La variable Tailnumber, dentro del método ReadData, es el identificador del que hablo en el punto 2 de arriba.
2. El codigo expuesto anteriormente es lo que estaba haciendo previamente, pero dado que se demora mucho en leer los datos y a veces tira la excepción OutOfMemoryException, empece a custionarme lo de contener todos los datos en memoria y de ahi surgieron las dudas de los tres puntos de arriba.

Comment: ¿La información contenida en el archivo CSV cambia con mucha frecuencia?

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez No, nunca cambia.

Comment: Y como el archivo CSV nunca cambia, ¿considerarías utilizar una base de datos? [Este enlace](https://www.sqlite.org/csv.html) de tablas temporales a partir de un CSV en SQLite pudiera ayudar. Aunque yo me inclinaría por crear una tabla permanente con esos datos.

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez !!Gracias!! Cree la tabla permanente como dijiste y funciona perfectamente las busquedas y todo. Antes no había trabajado con bases de datos, pero gracias a lo que me recomendastes ya pude realizar una pequeña introducción al tema.